# How to make session length last longer?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, jhipster, okta

I have a new JHipster project generated with version 6.1.2 and the authenticationType is oauth2.

I have configured oauth2 with Okta and things are working fine, except that 
I want the token to last longer than one hour.

I tried to change the settings in application.yml

```
server:
servlet:
 session:
   cookie:
     http-only: true
   timeout: 1440m
```

I want the session to last 24 hours (1440 minutes), but the change to application.yml makes no difference.

I am running the application in Azure with LinuxRuntime tomcat 9.0-jre8

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question:

I added the following config in /WEB-INF/web.xml and now the session lasts longer

```
     <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1440</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```